I don't understand this "(first %% is missing)" error
I'm having a problem with this jflex file. I derived it from some work I did on another language, itself derived from a lexer from a compilation course.
package Analyse;

import java_cup.runtime.*;
import Exceptions.AnalyseLexicaleException;

%%

%class AnalyseurLexical
%public

%line
%column

%type Symbol
%eofval{
        return symbol(CodesLexicaux.EOF) ;
%eofval}

// %unicode
%cup
// %debug

%{

  private StringBuilder chaine ;

  private Symbol symbol(int type) {
    return new Symbol(type, yyline, yycolumn) ;
  }

  private Symbol symbol(int type, Object value) {
    return new Symbol(type, yyline, yycolumn, value) ;
  }
%}

// Définition générales
// --------------------
chiffre = [0-9]
lettre = [a-zA-Z]
majuscule = [A-Z]
minuscule = [a-z]
chiffrelettre = {chiffre} | {lettre}
csteE = {chiffre}+
booleen = "true" | "false"
finDeLigne = \r|\n
espace = {finDeLigne}  | [ \t\f]
idvar = {minuscule}+
idalias = {majuscule}{chiffrelettre}*
idf = {lettre}+

%%
// Commentaires
// ------------
"//".*                 { /* DO NOTHING */ }

// Ponctuation
";"                    { return symbol(CodesLexicaux.SEMICOLON); }        // fin de commande
","                    { return symbol(CodesLexicaux.COMMA); }            // virgule

// Entiers
{csteE}                   { return symbol(CodesLexicaux.NUMBER, yytext()); } // entier

// Fractions
"/"                    { return symbol(CodesLexicaux.FRAC); }             // fraction

// Égalité des atomes de LQ
"="                    { return symbol(CodesLexicaux.EQUALS); }           // égalité

// Parenthèses
// -----------
"("                    { return symbol(CodesLexicaux.LPAREN); }
")"                    { return symbol(CodesLexicaux.RPAREN); }
"["                    { return symbol(CodesLexicaux.LBRACKET); }
"]"                    { return symbol(CodesLexicaux.RBRACKET); }
"{"                    { return symbol(CodesLexicaux.LBRACE); }
"}"                    { return symbol(CodesLexicaux.RBRACE); }

// Connecteurs logique
// -------------------
"not"                  { return symbol(CodesLexicaux.NOT); }               // négation logique
"and"                  { return symbol(CodesLexicaux.AND); }               // conjonction
"or"                   { return symbol(CodesLexicaux.OR); }                // disjonction
// "xor"                  { return symbol(CodesLexicaux.XOR); }              // ou exclusif
// "->"                   { return symbol(CodesLexicaux.IMPLIES); }          // implication
// "<->"                  { return symbol(CodesLexicaux.IIF); }              // équivalence

// Symboles de variation
"^"                    { return symbol(CodesLexicaux.TOTHE); }             // exposant
"."                    { return symbol(CodesLexicaux.DOT); }               // point
"+"                    { return symbol(CodesLexicaux.PLUS); }              // plus

// Commandes
// ---------
":="                   { return symbol(CodesLexicaux.ASSIGN); }            // affectation
"print"                { return symbol(CodesLexicaux.PRINT); }             // printing a result

// Identifiants de variables et d'alias
{idvar}                { return symbol(CodesLexicaux.IDVAR, yytext()); }   // identifiant de variable
{idalias}              { return symbol(CodesLexicaux.IDALIAS, yytext()); } // identifiant d'alias
{idf}                  { return symbol(CodesLexicaux.IDENTIFIER, yytext()); } // identifiant générique

// Divers
{espace}               { }

I only changed a few definitions, and changed a few things in the grammar.cup file. Now, I get this message, trying to parse the file test_parser.txt here :
Alpha := (a=1/1);

Reading "../../../Tests/test_parseur.var"

Error in file "../../../Tests/test_parseur.var" (line 1): 
This seems not to be a lexical specification (first %% is missing)
Alpha := (a=1/1);
1 error, 0 warnings.

So it seems the lexer can't read even the first tokens from this file... And I don't understand why. I think it has to do with only the JFlex file, but if the Grammar.cup is needed, I'll provide it.
